# Get Selected Value of select in table cell

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, onchange

I added a test script to detect the change of a html select and it is not firing.

The select is within a table cell and has a class of 'symselect'.  The table id is:  flogtable and the select is in the first row.

The jQuery test function I added is:

```
    $('.symselect').change(function() {
          alert('Handler for .change() called.');
     });
```

Comment: If the answers below don't work, you should provide your HTML markup in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling that code from within a domready block?

```
$(function() {
  $('.symselect').change(function() {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  });
});
```

Comment: Well no, but you need to wrap it within a domready function.  What's happening is $('.symselect') does not match anything because the select element does not exist yet. When you wrap the code within a domready function, as shown above, the code is not executed until the DOM has finished loading (meaning your elements are ready to work with).

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work:

```
$('#flogtable select.symselect').change(
    function() {
        alert('Handler for `change()` called.');
    });
```

Comment: Except that you made the selector *more* specific, which means less chance of a match. ;o)

Comment: @patrick: it does, but I figure that the specific selector lets us know that the concept works; once we know it works we can make it more general.

Comment: I guess my point is that since the handler isn't firing, and `.symselect` will select *all* `symselect` elements on the page, changing the selector to narrow it down to a smaller part of the page probably won't help the issue (though this may be the selector OP should eventually use).

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't fire. So I made a simple html file and still can't get it to fire.

Comment: Made a simple html doc and it still doesn't fire:

Comment: In Header:         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA [
          $('.symselect').change(function() {
              alert('Handler for .change() called.');
         });
        //]]>
    </script>

Comment: The select in body:   <select class="symselect">
           <option>FC--135 Flight</option>
           <option>PS--Pilot Service</option>
           <option>FE--Ferry Flight</option>
           <option>FT--Flight Training</option>
           <option>ST--SIM Training</option>
           <option>GT--Ground Training</option>
           <option>RON--RON</option>
           <option>LO--Lay Over</option>
           <option>OA--Other</option>
   </select>

Comment: Can you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), demo that reproduces this problem? Because it **should** work. So there must be something else going on, somewhere..?

Answer (score 0):

If I do:

```
$(function(){
  $('.symselect').change(function() {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  });
});
```

it works.